# Can I use cron from App Engine?

Tags: google-app-engine, cron

I'd like to write a web site using App Engine. The web site will be a front end for schedule the execution of some events that I plan to run with cron. Can I use cron from App Engine?

Anyone can provide an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is yes. Here are [the docs](http://code.google.com/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html) for Python.

Answer (score 0):

google shows it's possible with python.

http://code.google.com/intl/sk-SK/appengine/docs/python/config/cron.html